# Use useEffect to reinitialize useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component with a `<div contentEditable />` inside. The component is initialized with a `initialValue`. The `onChange` handler updates the `value`. It looks something like this:

```
const Editable = ({ initialValue }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  return (
    <div contentEditable onChange={event => setValue(event.currentTarget.value)}>
      {value}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now if the parent components passes a new `initialValue`, `value` and therefore the content of the `div` doesn't update since the state is already initialized.

Is it fine to use `useEffect` as follows in such a case or is there any other way?

```
const Editable = ({ initialValue }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  useEffect(() => setValue(initialValue), [initialValue]);

  return (
    <div contentEditable onChange={event => setValue(event.currentTarget.value)}>
      {value}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's completely fine to use it that way. You may want to rename `initialValue` to something like `value` to make it clear that it's not just the default value.

What you could do to clear up your code is create a custom hook that handles that exact situation like so:

```
const useUpdatingState = (value) => {
  const [internalValue, setInternalValue] = useState(value);
  useEffect(() => {
    setInternalValue(value)
  }, [value]);
  return [internalValue, setInternalValue];
};
```

This would make your code a little more readable and make the code reusable in other parts  of your code where you would want such behaviour.

Comment: You should not use the same variable names in the same context. It creates a shadow variable. Please refer to eslint rule 'no-shadow' https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow In this case rename func prop `value` to `newValue` or smth else

Comment: I had a working custom hook already doing exactly what you propose. Thanks for confirming :)

Comment: Isn't it a problem that `useEffect` is executed async?

Comment: @magic_al Not at all. `useState` is also executed asynchronously and in this custom hook only updates the value whenever `setInternalValue` is called and then passes the updated value down.
It's the same logic and code than if you implemented it right in your component. It just allows you to move the code in another file to allow it to be reused in other parts of you application.

Comment: @Linschlager if useEffect and useState are both executed async then above example could in theory cause two renderings. This is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

As proposed in the question, a `useEffect` is the correct solution.

```js
const Editable = ({ initialValue }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  useEffect(() => setValue(initialValue), [initialValue]);

  return (
    <div contentEditable onChange={event => setValue(event.currentTarget.value)}>
      {value}
    </div>
  );
};
```